# Picking up IP address from docker-compose.yml file and pass it to springboot app in the docker containers

Tags: linux, docker-compose, dockerfile, spring-cloud

I am running the same instance of Spring-boot application on docker clusters, Every cluster will have its own IP-Address. I want to configure the bootstrap and docker-compose.yml files in such a way that it will run on that cluster. But I am facing issues due to lack of ubuntu skills.

I am using Ubuntu Environment. Below are contents of my bootstrap.yml 
file:

`eureka: 
client: 
serviceUrl: 
defaultZone: http://${env.HOST_IP}:8761/eureka/ registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5`

I am creating a docker image out of this spring boot app. And I pass the value using docker-compose.yml file as shown below:

`eureka-server: 
image: controlsplm/eureka-server 
environment: HOST_IP: 13.68.114.134 
ports: - "8761:8761"`

.. But it somehow shows IP as `0.0.0.0` on startup

Now after certain attempt, I can see the environment variable is setting in yml file but somehow it is not picking up the IP

```
"Config": {
            "Hostname": "03774aec52c6",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8761/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "HOST_IP=13.68.114.134",
               "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u102",
                "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u102-b14.1-1~bpo8+1",
                "CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION=20140324"
            ],
```

Comment: Use an environment variable provided by the launcher.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Environment. Below are contents of my bootstrap.yml file:`eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${env.HOST_IP}:8761/eureka/
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5 `                                                          I am creating a docker image out of this springboot app. And i pass the value using docker-compose.yml file as shown below: `eureka-server:
  image: controlsplm/eureka-server
  environment:
      HOST_IP: 13.68.114.134  
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"`.. But it somehow shows IP as '0.0.0.0' on startup

Comment: @chrylis I hope I am enough clear with the scenario

Comment: What do you mean by "shows IP as 0.0.0.0 on startup" -- the environment variable? Or what is showing that IP?

Comment: @enderland Its shows IP. I wanted to make it dynamic such that it can load the required IP from the system variable.